# Should supporting algorithms be in their own class?

Tags: class-design, class

My `Widget` class has a method called `loadWidget`. This method needs to shuffle an array to work properly, among other things. In `Widget`, I could implement a Fisher-Yates shuffle as its own static method named `shuffle` and then call `shuffle` in `loadWidget`. However, this looks unseemly to me for two reasons:

1. The shuffling algorithm has little to do with `Widget` and putting 
   many unrelated algorithms there makes the class harder to read and 
   understand.
2. In the future, I may want to use the Fisher-Yates shuffle in other
   classes, but it feels like an anti-pattern to call `Widget.shuffle` whenever 
   I want to do that.

So the solution could be to create a class of support methods. I could call `SupportMethods.shuffle` inside `Widget` and other classes whenever I want to shuffle an array. Is this a good practice or does it violate design principles?

Comment: When shuffling the array, is a new array returned or is the existing array shuffled?

Comment: The existing one is shuffled. Curious to see what difference it makes here. :)

Comment: Where does the array come from? What class or piece of code is responsible for creating it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm always leery of static methods that have side effects (e.g. modifying data outside its own function call). Since the logic of the shuffling algorithm is likely closely intertwined with the code itself, you are probably unable to extract parts of the algorithm into helper functions.

I would recommend making the static method free of side effects by returning a shuffled copy of the original array. Depending on the array size and performance requirements this might not be desirable — but I would lean towards this approach unless you have a measured performance problem.

And even then, it won't hurt to have two copies of the shuffling algorithm around. One can return a shuffled copy of the array, and another can shuffle the existing array. Then you can have a version free of side effects, and another version called on a case-by-case basis that does have side affects. You can probably call one from the other:

```
// Modifies the existing array
SupportMethods.shuffle(array)

// Copies the array, then calls SupportMethods.shuffle(copyOfArray) and returns copyOfArray
SupportMethods.copyAndShuffle(array)
```

Be sure to name them differently and provide some additional hints in the documentation of this API.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a specific kind of shuffling, your basic intuition is *probably* right.

Assuming your `Widget`'s ["single responsibility"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) isn't "shuffling", it shouldn't know *much* about shuffling. A `Shuffler` class may be a good idea.

**But, I would really double-check your language and it's standard libraries first.** Make sure you're not overlooking a suitable shuffling or "randomizing" implementation there first.

If you *do* need (or really *want*) to implement your own shuffling, I strongly suggest making a `Shuffler` base class. When applicable, make it injectable into any class that needs shuffling so you can swap out shuffling algorithms and inject a `FakeShuffler` during testing ...

Comment: I'm curious to know why you would need a FakeShuffler for testing. If the shuffling/randomness of the collection is the thing you are testing in Widget, you are basically testing the shuffling algorithm. The algorithm, when in object form or static, should have its own tests.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It's not uncommon, from what I've seen, to need to provide fake randomness (or shuffling) to validate that your domain object is actually invoking a shuffle and that the resulting math, collection, state, etc. is as expected for the permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Why does a widget know about loading widgets? Why is it handling arrays of widgets?

This feels like your asking a book to do what a bookshelf does. Not very good semantics.

I'm in favor of moving this stuff out to `SuportingMethods` except that is a terrible name. Call it `WidgetRack` or `ArrayList<Widget>` or really any name that makes clear what does and doesn't belong in it. `SuportingMethods` is about as good a class name as `Misc`. You've created a [junk drawer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359441/131624).

With that broken out you could break it down further so WidgetRack doesn't have to know exactly what sort implementation it uses. But in any case let the `Widget` focus on being a `Widget`. Not on everything that happens to `Widget`s.

Comment: I could be wrong, but, I think you're reading too far into the question ... If the OP said they were loading a `List` of `Widget` with `Widget` specifically (don't think it said that), I'm really not sure it's relevant ... What if `Widget` is a `TreeNode` of some sort?

Comment: Or perhaps `Widget` is `AdvertisementPanel` and the `List` of things to be shuffled is a `List` of `AdBox`es or something ... I dunno. Either way, I think you're critiquing code you haven't actually seen instead of answering the question here.

Comment: @svidgen is correct; you don't know what the `Widget` class and `loadWidget` method do.

Comment: @Sid "... loadWidget. This method needs to shuffle an array" Silly me for assuming a method named loadWidget that shuffles would shuffle widgets. Would you mind editing the question to make the responsibilities clearer?

Comment: The name `Widget` and the main topic of my question should be an indication that the things you are focusing on are irrelevant. I do appreciate the insight in the second part of your answer, though.

Comment: By the way, I'm wondering how to do this then if I have many algorithms like shuffling that should be applied in many different classes (not just for `Widgets`). Would `ArrayAlgorithms` be a better name for the class? Does it also feel like the `java.util` library is a junk drawer? Thanks for the input.

Comment: @sid: The names "Widget" and "loadWidget" can imply some sort of behavior or responsibility. I think what candied_orange is trying to get at is what a Widget does, and what loadWidget does can be *very* relevant to this question. It may indicate you have another "thing" that can be modeled as its own class.

Comment: The comment area is not for discussions. If you need more input please edit your question so everyone can engage. The name Widget only indicates that you're deliberately not using a useful name. Like Foo or Thingy. Gives me no idea what it's responsibility is. Nothing else did either so I guessed. I expressed my confusion at the first. Edit the question to make this clear and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I believe the question is clear already, at least multiple people (including you) have given me useful answers. I was inviting you to expand on your answer, not to have a conversation in chat. By the way, I come here in peace, so you could tone down the sarcasm ("silly me," etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to discuss problems like these with generic names like `Widget`. Usually, a class you are tempted to name something like `Utilities` or `SupportMethods` is going to end up not very cohesive, but there are other groupings that might work for you.

If your language has extension methods, you can group functions like `shuffle` together with other extension methods on arrays. You could group it in a `Random` class with other related methods. Another option is to create a `WidgetLoader` or `WidgetFactory` class and put all the methods related to loading but not using a `Widget` in there, splitting off `shuffle` into a different class only if future circumstances dictate.

The exact reason methods are grouped together doesn't matter nearly as much as the fact that a common reason exists and is easy to articulate.